# Webscraper function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im making a webscraping function to make a json with the data, the webscraper part works, wierd thing is that the function returns undefined

getproduct.js

```
module.exports.getproduct = url => {
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(body => {
      let product;
      const $ = cheerio.load(body);
      product = {
        productName: $(".product-name").text()
      };
      console.log(product);
      return product;
    });
};
```

index.js

```
const {getproduct} = require('./webScraper/getproduct');

console.log(getproduct('https://www.americanas.com.br/produto/134118928'));
```

the console.log(product); works fine, but the console.log on the index.js prints nothing. What im missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `return` statement in javascript only belongs to it's closest surrounding function. You have one return statement in your code, and it belongs to a different function than you might expect:

```
.then(body => {
  ...
  return product;
})
```

So the `return` statement will only return a value to that function.
You main function, `getproducts`, actually has no return statements in it, thus it does return undefined. Adding a return in front of your `fetch` solves that, but we are not yet done:

```
return fetch(url)
```

Because `fetch` and the `.then`-s that follow will not just return the value. The return a `Promise`. Promises are hard concepts, and something I will not be able to explain here, so I would suggest reading more about that if you are not sure about them yet :)

The main take-away is to get the value out of the promise, you have to use `.then` or `await`, more on `await` later, lets stay with `.then` first:

```
getproduct('https://www.americanas.com.br/produto/134118928')
.then(product => {
  console.log('product:', product);
});
```

Now, people realized that writing all your code that does something with promises in chains of `.then(...).then(...)`-s would be a bit frustrating, so we (the javascript community) invented `async/await`. That way you can write your code like this:

```
module.exports.getproduct = async (url) => {
  let response = await fetch(url);
  let body = await response.text();
  let $ = cheerio.load(body);
  let product = {
    productName: $(".product-name").text()
  };
  console.log(product);
  return product;
};
```

Now it looks a lot nicer, and you can see that the `return` statement actually is in the right function again! Beware though, you still need not forget to put `await` before functions that would normally require a `.then` at the end, but it is definitely easier.

Now you `index.js` is a little trickier, as you can only use `await` in a function that is marked with `async`, but we can:

```
const {getproduct} = require('./webScraper/getproduct');

let main = async () => {
  let product = await getproduct('https://www.americanas.com.br/produto/134118928');
  console.log('product:', product);
}
main();
```

I hope it is a little clearer how you can move forward from here :)

Answer (score 0):

Should add async function wrapper and await promise

```
// getproduct.js

module.exports.getproduct = url => {
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(body => {
      const $ = cheerio.load(body);
      const product = {
        productName: $(".product-name").text()
      };
      console.log('getproduct.js > product', product);
      return product;
    });
};


//index.js updated file

const {getproduct} = require('./webScraper/getproduct');

(async () => {
   const product = await getproduct('https://www.americanas.com.br/produto/134118928');
   console.log('index.js > product', product);
})();
```